# Multiple selection dialog for dynamic data on Notes Web

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, ibm-domino

This might be a basic question but I am not sure how to do. Please advise me.

I need to create a UI, which a user can select some of items on Notes Web. The items are changed by various settings. So I can't simply pick up the items from Notes view.

The requirements are

```
1. List the items for end-user when clicking a button on Notes Web document
2. The end-user can select multiple items from the list
3. The selected items are saved in the Notes Web document
```

Is this need to use XPages repeat-contro? But I'm not enough knowledge for Javascript. Is there any method? Or Are there any sample codes/templates?

Comment: Why does this not work? 1. There's a categorized view of the items, with a multi-valued key field that contains all setting values that apply to each item. 2. Click the user and get list of the user's settings. 3. Construct a key list using the user's settings. 4. Do a lookup into the view using the key list that was constructed for the user.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But sorry I can't understand what I should do

I need to prepare data from multipe views in multiple DBs. Then the data are stored in a program object(e.g. Array). I'd like to list the variable data in Notes Web UI.Then a user can select multiple data in the list and store the data in the document.
There is lots of samples to use a datasource as a view but I don't find the case.

Comment: You didn't mention that it's multiple databases. That clearly makes it a much broader question, and without a lot more detail and specificity I don't think it's something that can be answered here.